# How to check the type of T object?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a function.

```
protected Boolean MainFunction<T>(T objectData, string Id, out string Value)
{
    //here I need to check whether T equal the object I need or not 
}
```

And the above `MainFunction` is called by `Function1` and `Function2` where I pass `MyObject1` and `MyObject2`.

I want to check `T objectData` whether it is `MyObject1` or `MyObject2` inside `MainFunction`. Please give me any suggestions.

```
public bool Function1(string ID, out string Value, out ErrorReport error)
{
    return MainFunction(Data.MyObject1, ID, out Value, out error);
}

public bool Function2(string ID, out string Value, out ErrorReport error)
{
    return MainFunction(Data.MyObject2, ID, out Value, out error);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of why you need to know the type being passed?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this: `"I want to check T objectData is whether MyObject1 or MyObject2 inside MainFunction"` - What are you trying to determine?

Comment: Have a base class for `MyObject1` and `MyObject2` and use a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) like `where T: BaseClass`, but you may reconsider your design, if you are checking the type in generic method then you probably don't need generics.

Comment: I mean the parameter objectData in the MainFunction is if MyObject1 or MyObject2 because I am passing different Object type to MainFunction.

Comment: I agree with Patrick in his answer, looks like you would be better off with an overload instead of generics here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you don't use generics for things that aren't, just because it looks nice or deduplicate code. If that is the case, proceed.

Second, you can use `is` to check if the type matches the one you need:

```
if (objectData is MyObject1)
{
    ...
}
else if (objectData is MyObject2)
{
    ...
}
```

If you have control over the types, you could also use a base class and use the generic constraint to narrow down the types `T` can be:

```
Boolean MainFunction<T>(T objectData, string Id, out string Value) where T : BaseClass
{
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry I left to include where T: BaseClass in my question.

Comment: Hi, I understood by your answer and had more reading at MSDN about generic. Thank you for your help.